# Adobe Flash CS6 - FLVPlayback Start From Time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flvplayback

*I'm working with Adobe Flash CS6 with Action Script 3.0*

**This is what I have:**

This is just a simple explanation of my project. I have 2 pages (frames) in my project: `Scene Selection` and `Watch Video`.

On `Watch Video`, I have a video which play automatically. This video consists of 3 parts: `Part 1`, `Part 2`, and `Part 3`. I also have button `Home` to go back to `Scene Selection`.

On `Scene Selection`, I have 3 images which act as buttons: `Part 1`, `Part 2`, and `Part 3`. If I click button `Part 2`, I will be directed to `Watch Video` page, and the video will be skipped to `Part 2`.

**This is the code:**

```
//Scene Selection
btnPart1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickPart1);
function OnClickPart1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //I think something is missing here
    gotoAndStop(3);
}


//Watch Video
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import fl.video.VideoPlayer;
import flash.events.Event;

var flvPlayer:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
var vp:VideoPlayer = flvPlayer.getVideoPlayer(0);

addChild(flvPlayer);
flvPlayer.x = 162.5;
flvPlayer.y = 100;
flvPlayer.width = 1024;
flvPlayer.height = 576;
flvPlayer.source = "Final.mp4";
flvPlayer.skin = "SkinOverPlaySeekMute.swf"
flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0xF9D760;

btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickHome);
function OnClickHome(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    CleanFlvPlayer();
}
function CleanFlvPlayer():void{
    vp.close();
    removeChild(flvPlayer);
}
```

**This is the question:**

I don't have problem with `Part 1`, because it works just like I want. But, how can I skipped the video to a certain time? I can't separate the video into each part, because my real project is more complicated than this. What code should I add? Thanks.

Comment: Prior to asking this question, did you try to at least read the official documentation: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#seek()

Comment: @Organis I have searched on the internet and on the official documentation too, but I didn't find that one. So, I have to place that code inside `OnClickPart2` function. Is that right?

Comment: You can call it (obviously) after the video url is assigned to component. Otherwise, no restrictions. The correct moment is totally up to you.

Comment: @Organis I have added these lines to function OnClickPart2: `gotoAndStop(3); vp.seek(20); flvPlayer.autoPlay = true;`, but the video won't play automatically like before. What should I do?

Comment: @GraceMichelle if still struggling to make it work, also consider `NetStream` as a customised playback system instead of `FLVPlayback`. With N.Stream, for `OnClickPart2` function, you can just say `my_NS_var.seek(x)` where `x` is the seconds to seek to, followed by `my_NS_var.play()` to start playing `x`seconds...

Comment: @GraceMichelle if using `vp.seek(20);` then shouldn't it be `vp.autoPlay = true;` also? Or else seek with `flvPlayer.seek(20)` then `flvPlayer.autoPlay = true;` will make sense...

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your advice of using `NetStream`, but for this project I'll pass, because I'll have to change many parts of my code. I've tried changing my code into `flvPlayer.seek` and `flvPlayer.autoPlay`, and it works! Thanks for your help! I've upvoted your comment

Comment: @Organis Thanks for your help! I've upvoted your comment